# iOS Static library getting "no source files to build from... target membership" error

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

Im trying to sort out a strange issue, downloading http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/ and trying to create a static framework. The following error occurs right from the start:

Framework target "RWAEngineLibrary" had no source files to build from. Make sure your source files have the correct target membership

Googling yielded no results.. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!